# Could not find adb.exe on my tools folder

Tags: android, sdk, nexus-one

I just bought the HTC Nexus One and i'm trying to create Air application fon Android. I have downloaded Android SDK for windows and i installed it, but on the tools folder i can't find the adb.exe 
I'm watching the following video http://www.gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=123 that shows the steps from the beginning how to setup Air Applications for Android.

Using the command prompt i want to check if my device is connected to the pc using the "adb devices" command.

I installed all the available packages for the Android SDK including Usb Driver package, revision 4.

However i dont have this file. Can you advice me what to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be in the platform-tools folder