# Android Problem: Eclipse cannot find ADB.exe

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

First, I know this problem has been asked before, namely : [Could not find adb.exe on my tools folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659014/could-not-find-adb-exe-on-my-tools-folder)

but I tried every answer given and none work (even the accepted answer).

My problem is that I updated the Android SDK and now Eclipse cannot find adb.exe. I know where it is, it is in platform-tools directory, but I can't get Eclipse to read it from there. I updated the path.
Now what has happened is, in all my projects the asset folder is empty, meaning there is no android jar file. 
Also, clicking on the SDK update manager from inside eclipse does nothing. I have no idea why.
Lastly, if I try to install new software in Eclipse (ADT update?) it wont allow it.

In the project -> preferences tab I get the following message:

> Could not find C:\Program
>   Files\android-sdk-windows\tools\adb.exe!

I'm working on Windows 7 with Galileo eclipse.
Can anyone offer any help?

Comment: try uninstalling ADT (since you can't update) and reinstalling it. Sounds like a conflict of versions between the SDK + ADT is causing the problem. (Old ADT looks for old ADB location \tools rather than \platform-tools)

Comment: You mean delete the ADT file from the eclipse\plugins directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is simple. Unfortunately I forgot you need admin rights. That's why eclipse wouldn't install new packages. I simply opened Eclipse as the Admin and everything went smoothly. Lost all my R.java files for some reason, but got them back by cleaning the project(s).

Answer (score 5):

The `adb` tool has moved to `platform-tools/`

If you don't see this directory in your SDK, launch the SDK and AVD Manager (execute the android tool) and install "Android SDK Platform-tools"

Answer (score 5):

I also faced the same problem before but now i solved the problem by following the step below

> Step 1: You know where your android-sdk is installed in your system if you didnt changed the location search in ProgramFiles/Android
>
> step 2: close eclipse.
>
> Step 3: Copy adb.exe in **android-sdk/platform-tools/** folder
>
> Step 4: Paste that adb.exe in **android-sdk/tools/** folder
>
> Step 5: Now open eclipse go to **Windows --> Preferences** choose android then click browse and select android-sdk with in few minutes it shows APK levels installed in your system press Apply

Comment: Thx! this worked on my Mac too. I had to copy and paste adb binary file from platform-tools to tools, to have eclipse see it.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's because adb has moved to
`C:\Program Files\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe`

Comment: I can confirm it moved there. The problem is Eclipse refuses to acknowledge it.

Comment: Have you tried to go to Window->Preferences->Android and re-set the android SDK location?

Comment: You should rather click `Help -> Install Updates`

Answer (score 0):

I 've tried this once.. when i got similar problem on Windows 7 .. Copy adb.exe from platform-tools to tools folder. Now eclipse should work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes on tools/adb_has_moved you can read:

> *"The adb tool has moved to platform-tools/ If you don't see this directory in your SDK, launch the SDK and AVD Manager (execute the
>   android tool) and install "Android SDK Platform-tools" Please also
>   update your PATH environment variable to include the platform-tools/
>   directory, so you can execute adb from any location."*

the adb tool has moved to `platform-tools/` but in my case no `adb` was in this dir but in windows 7 you can **make backup of this folder (just go in folder properties->Previous version)** and save backup instead of original. In my case it helps

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem. In my case it was caused by an upgrade on the Java JDK. I was using 1.6 and upgraded to 1.7.

Just manually add the new JDK to Eclipse.

Right click on your project JRE System Library. Select installed JRE, and then find it on your computer.