# Appium test script error: Could not find 'adb.exe'

Tags: appium, appium-android

**Hi,
I am learning Appium and this is my first automation script for appium. 
Getting below error while running simple program to open calculator application in Android device. 
It says that could not find 'adb.exe' but its there in the SDK tools folder. Also I have set ANDROID_HOME in Environment variables and have PATH variable accordingly.Please help.**

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create a new remote session. Please check the server log for more details. Original error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not find 'adb.exe' in ["C:\Users\Bhushan\Documents\Automation Testing 2020\Android SDK Tools\android\cmdline-tools\latest\platform-tools\adb.exe","C:\Users\Bhushan\Documents\Automation Testing 2020\Android SDK Tools\android\cmdline-tools\latest\emulator\adb.exe","C:\Users\Bhushan\Documents\Automation Testing 2020\Android SDK Tools\android\cmdline-tools\latest\tools\adb.exe","C:\Users\Bhushan\Documents\Automation Testing 2020\Android SDK Tools\android\cmdline-tools\latest\tools\bin\adb.exe"]. Do you have Android Build Tools installed at 'C:\Users\Bhushan\Documents\Automation Testing 2020\Android SDK Tools\android\cmdline-tools\latest'?
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-TN4V3G6', ip: '192.168.99.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '13.0.2'
Driver info: driver.version: AppiumDriver
remote stacktrace: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not find 'adb.exe' in ["C:\Users\Bhushan\Documents\Automation Testing 2020\Android SDK Tools\android\cmdline-tools\latest\platform-tools\adb.exe","C:\Users\Bhushan\Documents\Automation Testing 2020\Android SDK Tools\android\cmdline-tools\latest\emulator\adb.exe","C:\Users\Bhushan\Documents\Automation Testing 2020\Android SDK Tools\android\cmdline-tools\latest\tools\adb.exe","C:\Users\Bhushan\Documents\Automation Testing 2020\Android SDK Tools\android\cmdline-tools\latest\tools\bin\adb.exe"]. Do you have Android Build Tools installed at 'C:\Users\Bhushan\Documents\Automation Testing 2020\Android SDK Tools\android\cmdline-tools\latest'?
    at getResponseForW3CError (C:\Program Files\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\errors.js:804:9)
    at asyncHandler (C:\Program Files\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\protocol.js:388:37)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-TN4V3G6', ip: '192.168.99.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '13.0.2'
Driver info: driver.version: AppiumDriver
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:208)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:217)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:239)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:41)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.startSession(AppiumDriver.java:336)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:37)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:88)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:98)
    at AppTest1.openCalculator(AppTest1.java:36)
    at AppTest1.main(AppTest1.java:16)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:186)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not find 'adb.exe' in ["C:\Users\Bhushan\Documents\Automation Testing 2020\Android SDK Tools\android\cmdline-tools\latest\platform-tools\adb.exe","C:\Users\Bhushan\Documents\Automation Testing 2020\Android SDK Tools\android\cmdline-tools\latest\emulator\adb.exe","C:\Users\Bhushan\Documents\Automation Testing 2020\Android SDK Tools\android\cmdline-tools\latest\tools\adb.exe","C:\Users\Bhushan\Documents\Automation Testing 2020\Android SDK Tools\android\cmdline-tools\latest\tools\bin\adb.exe"]. Do you have Android Build Tools installed at 'C:\Users\Bhushan\Documents\Automation Testing 2020\Android SDK Tools\android\cmdline-tools\latest'?
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-TN4V3G6', ip: '192.168.99.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '13.0.2'
Driver info: driver.version: AppiumDriver
remote stacktrace: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not find 'adb.exe' in ["C:\Users\Bhushan\Documents\Automation Testing 2020\Android SDK Tools\android\cmdline-tools\latest\platform-tools\adb.exe","C:\Users\Bhushan\Documents\Automation Testing 2020\Android SDK Tools\android\cmdline-tools\latest\emulator\adb.exe","C:\Users\Bhushan\Documents\Automation Testing 2020\Android SDK Tools\android\cmdline-tools\latest\tools\adb.exe","C:\Users\Bhushan\Documents\Automation Testing 2020\Android SDK Tools\android\cmdline-tools\latest\tools\bin\adb.exe"]. Do you have Android Build Tools installed at 'C:\Users\Bhushan\Documents\Automation Testing 2020\Android SDK Tools\android\cmdline-tools\latest'?
    at getResponseForW3CError (C:\Program Files\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\errors.js:804:9)
    at asyncHandler (C:\Program Files\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\protocol.js:388:37)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$errorHandler$0(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:62)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$0(HandshakeResponse.java:30)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:127)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:502)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:488)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:543)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:128)
    ... 18 more

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Step 1: You know where your android-sdk is installed in your system. if you didn't changed the location search in ProgramFiles/Android

Step 2: close eclipse.

Step 3: Copy adb.exe in android-sdk/platform-tools/ folder

Step 4: Paste that adb.exe in android-sdk/tools/ folder

Step 5: Now open eclipse go to Windows --> Preferences choose android then click browse and select android-sdk with in few minutes

[Android Problem: Eclipse cannot find ADB.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6361349/android-problem-eclipse-cannot-find-adb-exe)

Comment: Thanks Raghav, I tried to follow all steps mentioned  as above however I am facing issue in 5th Step. I am not getting Android in Windows->Preferences in Eclipse. Does it mean that I need to re-install SDK tools?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10310028/why-doesnt-android-appear-in-eclipses-preferences